KeyError: 'The `end` argument could not be matched to a location related to the index of the data
following is my code:
# Perform ARIMA time series forecasting for Apple stock prices

model = ARIMA(apple_data["Close"], order=(1, 0, 0))
results = model.fit()
start="2023-12-01"
# Predict future stock prices
predictions = results.predict(freq="D", start=start, end=pd.to_datetime(start) + pd.DateOffset(days=39))
print(predictions)

I am trying to find out prediction for coming 60 days but in output I'm getting below error:
C:\Users\Sonu-PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py:473: ValueWarning: A date index has been provided, but it has no associated frequency information and so will be ignored when e.g. forecasting.
  self._init_dates(dates, freq)
C:\Users\Sonu-PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py:473: ValueWarning: A date index has been provided, but it has no associated frequency information and so will be ignored when e.g. forecasting.
  self._init_dates(dates, freq)
C:\Users\Sonu-PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py:473: ValueWarning: A date index has been provided, but it has no associated frequency information and so will be ignored when e.g. forecasting.
  self._init_dates(dates, freq)
C:\Users\Sonu-PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\sarimax.py:966: UserWarning: Non-stationary starting autoregressive parameters found. Using zeros as starting parameters.
  warn('Non-stationary starting autoregressive parameters'
C:\Users\Sonu-PC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py:249: FutureWarning: Indexing a timezone-aware DatetimeIndex with a timezone-naive datetime is deprecated and will raise KeyError in a future version. Use a timezone-aware object instead.
  loc = row_labels.get_loc(key)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:548, in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:2263, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

File pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi:2273, in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1610168400000000000

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3802, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3801 try:
-> 3802     return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3803 except KeyError as err:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:516, in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\index.pyx:550, in pandas._libs.index.DatetimeEngine.get_loc()

KeyError: Timestamp('2021-01-09 00:00:00-0500', tz='America/New_York')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py:736, in DatetimeIndex.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    735 try:
--> 736     return Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    737 except KeyError as err:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py:3804, in Index.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3803 except KeyError as err:
-> 3804     raise KeyError(key) from err
   3805 except TypeError:
   3806     # If we have a listlike key, _check_indexing_error will raise
   3807     #  InvalidIndexError. Otherwise we fall through and re-raise
   3808     #  the TypeError.

KeyError: Timestamp('2021-01-09 00:00:00-0500', tz='America/New_York')

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py:249, in get_index_label_loc(key, index, row_labels)
    248 if not isinstance(key, (int, np.integer)):
--> 249     loc = row_labels.get_loc(key)
    250 else:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\datetimes.py:738, in DatetimeIndex.get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
    737 except KeyError as err:
--> 738     raise KeyError(orig_key) from err

KeyError: Timestamp('2021-01-09 00:00:00')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py:369, in get_prediction_index(start, end, nobs, base_index, index, silent, index_none, index_generated, data)
    368 try:
--> 369     end, end_index, end_oos = get_index_label_loc(
    370         end, base_index, data.row_labels
    371     )
    372 except KeyError:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py:281, in get_index_label_loc(key, index, row_labels)
    280     except:
--> 281         raise e
    282 return loc, index, index_was_expanded

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py:245, in get_index_label_loc(key, index, row_labels)
    244 try:
--> 245     loc, index, index_was_expanded = get_index_loc(key, index)
    246 except KeyError as e:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py:195, in get_index_loc(key, index)
    194 except (IndexError, ValueError) as e:
--> 195     raise KeyError(str(e))
    196 loc = key

KeyError: 'only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[115], line 7
      5 start="2020-12-01"
      6 # Predict future stock prices
----> 7 predictions = results.predict(freq="D", start=start, end=pd.to_datetime(start) + pd.DateOffset(days=39))
      8 print(predictions)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\base\wrapper.py:113, in make_wrapper.<locals>.wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    111     obj = data.wrap_output(func(results, *args, **kwargs), how[0], how[1:])
    112 elif how:
--> 113     obj = data.wrap_output(func(results, *args, **kwargs), how)
    114 return obj

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\mlemodel.py:3487, in MLEResults.predict(self, start, end, dynamic, information_set, signal_only, **kwargs)
   3422 r"""
   3423 In-sample prediction and out-of-sample forecasting
   3424 
   (...)
   3484     including confidence intervals.
   3485 """
   3486 # Perform the prediction
-> 3487 prediction_results = self.get_prediction(
   3488     start, end, dynamic, information_set=information_set,
   3489     signal_only=signal_only, **kwargs)
   3490 return prediction_results.predicted_mean

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\statespace\mlemodel.py:3340, in MLEResults.get_prediction(self, start, end, dynamic, information_set, signal_only, index, exog, extend_model, extend_kwargs, **kwargs)
   3336     start = 0
   3338 # Handle start, end, dynamic
   3339 start, end, out_of_sample, prediction_index = (
-> 3340     self.model._get_prediction_index(start, end, index))
   3342 # Handle `dynamic`
   3343 if isinstance(dynamic, (str, dt.datetime, pd.Timestamp)):

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py:836, in TimeSeriesModel._get_prediction_index(self, start, end, index, silent)
    780 """
    781 Get the location of a specific key in an index or model row labels
    782 
   (...)
    833 since we have required them to be full indexes, there is no ambiguity).
    834 """
    835 nobs = len(self.endog)
--> 836 return get_prediction_index(
    837     start,
    838     end,
    839     nobs,
    840     base_index=self._index,
    841     index=index,
    842     silent=silent,
    843     index_none=self._index_none,
    844     index_generated=self._index_generated,
    845     data=self.data,
    846 )

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py:373, in get_prediction_index(start, end, nobs, base_index, index, silent, index_none, index_generated, data)
    369     end, end_index, end_oos = get_index_label_loc(
    370         end, base_index, data.row_labels
    371     )
    372 except KeyError:
--> 373     raise KeyError(
    374         "The `end` argument could not be matched to a"
    375         " location related to the index of the data."
    376     )
    378 # Handle slices (if the given index keys cover more than one date)
    379 if isinstance(start, slice):

KeyError: 'The `end` argument could not be matched to a location related to the index of the data.'

Here is the data:
import yfinance as yf

apple = yf.Ticker("AAPL")
apple_data = apple.history(period="1d", start="2010-01-01", end="2024-01-01")
print(apple_data.head())

Previously it was showing KeyError for start and now it's showing for end. My objective is to predict stock prices from 2024-01-01 to 2024-03-01. I appreciate any help or hint to counter the error.
